# I need help finding a problem to research and solve for HS research project

Tags: process, development-process, small-projects

Short version: I want to do a research project, but for the life of me I cannot think of an original problem to solve that isn't already being solved. (also for the record, if I am in the wrong discussion website, please point me towards the proper one in which to voice my question)

This semester at my High School I will be taking a class titled Problems and Solutions in which I will have a semester to identify and research a problem in a field that interests me, solve the problem via experimentation and the scientific method, and then present my findings.  I began by scouring news, fields, other's research in an attempt to isolate a problem that I could solve.  Finding, or rather coming up with, a problem has proved difficult for me, although I (tentatively) narrowed my fields of interest down to the following:

Better solar power,
Wireless solar power transmission from altitude,
Communication network for autonomous vehicles,
Aeroelasticity?,
Solar Sail Elasticity?,
Desalination? Of groundwater (Solar?),
Quantum Tunneling? (not really realistic research for a 10th grader, just a cool topic),
        and EEg Prosthetics

These are not in anyway what I plan to limit myself if a better project presents itself, just specifics that I came up with.  I was wondering if you could give me advice for finding a problem to solve in these (or any fields, I'm interested in a lot), link some examples, or even point me towards some research that I could build upon.

Also, I forgot to mention that in the 'fields of interest' that I have narrowed down to I have read quite a bit about the research being done concerning each one, such as research on Eeg Prosthetic algorithms or Google's work in the neural networks of self driving cars. I thought that being knowledgable on the subjects would allow me to find a problem but I only found what already has been solved.

I really appreciate your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a project management problem or issue

Comment: That's fine but is there anywhere I can go to ask?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not likely to be anywhere on the Stack Exchange network where this is on-topic because SE are Q&A sites rather than discussion sites or general suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: Like Marv I'm not sure where you can ask this - Quora maybe? This paper - http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.molcel.2009.09.013 - might be of interest. Choose something very narrow (like, really narrow). Anything else will be insurmountable because solving huge problems is a long term (and most likely) group endeavour. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

### Find a topic that is locally relevant

Here is one suggestion for narrowing down your area of focus. Find a topic that is locally relevant. How to determine whether a topic is locally relevant?

To take an example, let us say you want to come up with an improved Prosthetic device. Find, at a minimum, three people in your local area who will benefit from that improvement. This way you will be solving a real problem instead of a theoretical problem. You can bounce your ideas off of them and get valuable feedback to set clear goals for your project. For example, they can tell you what options are currently available and what are their limitations. And what is the top most improvement that will make their life easier. And what is a cost they can afford.

Similarly for Solar Power or Desalination find three local firms or individuals who will benefit from that work.

If it works for some people in your local area, it is bound to be of wider interest. Once you have a solution, you can see how to extend it to a wider audience.